# wl.client.init Usage in IONIC 2 + MFP 8.0.0-2017012016

Tags: cordova, ionic2, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using Ionic 2 and MFP(8.0.0-2017012016). I've faced an issue in usage of **Wl.Client.init(options)**.

My app is working ,even if I'm not using this code.

I have made **clientCustominit** as true in config.xml.
And I tried to use this in my custom function.
 It doesn't make any effect in app

But, Still I'm able to connect to my server.

How does this happen? Please help...

Comment: You do not need to explicitly call init() function. The initialization happens after mfp plugin is initialized. And in your custom function, does the application initialize flow enter this custom method?

Comment: Actually I tried to do SSL pinning. my intention is, once SSL pinning is ready, next to call init(). 
But, I have made clientCustominit as true in config.xml. So, it shouldn't exceute the Wl.Client.init(options). But it does that. This is my confusion..